# DirectShow video filter displays blank/frozen screen on GraphEdit

Tags: c++, winapi, com, directshow

I am entirely new to DirectShow development so for testing purposes / as a stepping stone I am trying to create a filter which generates a 640x480 video with random colors assigned to every pixel for every frame. I looked at the DirectShow filter samples included in the Windows SDK and modeled my code on them.

When I insert my filter in GraphEdit from the SDK, however, all that gets displayed is a 640x480 white window. Well, not exactly white, considering when the window gets resized to be larger everything outside the 640x480 boundaries turns black, and when maximized, it freezes part of the background with it.

The same issue occurs when I try inserting any of the sample filters in the SDK, so the problem may not be within my code. **[Read UPDATE]**

I displayed my implementation of the output pin below. I apologize for the massive chunk of code, but I am not sure what part of it could be causing the issue. I realize it isn't exactly polished, but like I said it's for testing purposes.

```
class COutputPin : public CSourceStream
{
private:
    CCritSec m_cSharedState;
    CRefTime currTime;
    int frameLength;

public:
    COutputPin(HRESULT* phr, CSource* pFilter) : CSourceStream("Output Pin", phr, pFilter, L"Out")
    {
        currTime = 0;
        frameLength = 20;
    }

    HRESULT GetMediaType(int iPosition, CMediaType* pmt)
    {
        CheckPointer(pmt, E_POINTER);
        CAutoLock cAutoLock(m_pFilter->pStateLock());

        if (iPosition < 0)
            return E_INVALIDARG;

        if (iPosition > 0)
            return VFW_S_NO_MORE_ITEMS;

        VIDEOINFO* pvi = (VIDEOINFO*)pmt->AllocFormatBuffer(sizeof(VIDEOINFO));
        if (NULL == pvi)
            return(E_OUTOFMEMORY);

        ZeroMemory(pvi, sizeof(VIDEOINFO));
        
        pvi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        pvi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8;
        pvi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = iPALETTE_COLORS;
        pvi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        pvi->bmiHeader.biWidth = 640;
        pvi->bmiHeader.biHeight = 480;
        pvi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        pvi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = GetBitmapSize(&pvi->bmiHeader);
        pvi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

        SetRectEmpty(&(pvi->rcSource));
        SetRectEmpty(&(pvi->rcTarget));

        pmt->SetType(&MEDIATYPE_Video);
        pmt->SetFormatType(&FORMAT_VideoInfo);
        pmt->SetTemporalCompression(FALSE);

        const GUID SubTypeGUID = GetBitmapSubtype(&pvi->bmiHeader);
        pmt->SetSubtype(&SubTypeGUID);
        pmt->SetSampleSize(pvi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage);

        return NOERROR;
    }

    HRESULT CheckMediaType(const CMediaType* pMediaType)
    {
        CheckPointer(pMediaType, E_POINTER);

        if ((*(pMediaType->Type()) != MEDIATYPE_Video) || !(pMediaType->IsFixedSize()))
        {
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        }

        const GUID* SubType = pMediaType->Subtype();
        if (SubType == NULL || *SubType != MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB8)
        {
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        }

        VIDEOINFO* pvi = (VIDEOINFO*)pMediaType->Format();

        if (pvi == NULL)
        {
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        }

        if (pvi->bmiHeader.biWidth != 640 || abs(pvi->bmiHeader.biHeight) != 480)
        {
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        }

        if (pvi->bmiHeader.biHeight < 0)
        {
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        }

        return S_OK;

    }

    HRESULT DecideBufferSize(IMemAllocator* pAlloc, ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES* pProperties)
    {
        CheckPointer(pAlloc, E_POINTER);
        CheckPointer(pProperties, E_POINTER);

        CAutoLock cAutoLock(m_pFilter->pStateLock());
        HRESULT hr = NOERROR;

        VIDEOINFO* pvi = (VIDEOINFO*)m_mt.Format();
        pProperties->cBuffers = 1;
        pProperties->cbBuffer = pvi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage;

        ASSERT(pProperties->cbBuffer);
        ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES Actual;
        hr = pAlloc->SetProperties(pProperties, &Actual);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            return hr;
        }

        if (Actual.cbBuffer < pProperties->cbBuffer)
        {
            return E_FAIL;
        }

        ASSERT(Actual.cBuffers == 1);
        return NOERROR;
    }

    HRESULT FillBuffer(IMediaSample* pSample)
    {
        BYTE* pData;
        long cbData;

        CheckPointer(pSample, E_POINTER);
        CAutoLock cAutoLockShared(&m_cSharedState);

        pSample->GetPointer(&pData);
        cbData = pSample->GetSize();

        for (long i = 0; i < cbData; i++)
        {
            pData[i] = rand() % 0xFF;
        }
        
        CRefTime rtStart = currTime;
        currTime += (LONG)frameLength;
        pSample->SetTime((REFERENCE_TIME*) &rtStart, (REFERENCE_TIME*) &currTime);

        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP Notify(IBaseFilter* pSelf, Quality q)
    {    
        return NOERROR;
    }
};
```

Upon debugging the Notify function I found that a Famine quality message gets thrown on the first frame, with a Flood message on every frame afterwards. That said I still haven't been able to figure out the issue.

My machine is running Windows 10. Any help is appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:** I have discovered some strange behavior with GraphEdit. Apparently the sample filters from the SDK (`ball` in this case) exhibit the same behavior as my code only when run once, but when two instances are run at the same time the second one works fine. But then when the first one is closed, the second one freezes.

When I tried replicating this with my filter I found that the first instance displays a white/frozen window, while the second one a completely black window. I have no idea what to make of this.

Comment: I don't see you're doing `IMediaSample::SetActualDataLength`

Comment: @RomanR. I added `pSample->SetActualDataLength(bufferSize)` at the end of FillBuffer() with the buffer size being the same as in the header (640x480). It returns S_OK but still no change in behaviour.